# Django using URL parameters in template

Tags: django, templates, url

I need to redirect to another page with same url parameters so I don't understand how to use url parameters in current template to redirect.

dborg.html:

```
{% extends './frame.html' %}

{% block content %}

<a href="{% url 'create_user' {{orgtype}} {{deg}} %}">Создать нового пользователя</a>
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
{% for i in o %}
<p><a href='{% url "view_user" i.id %}'>{{i.fld}}</a></p>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name='main'),
    path('view_org/<str:orgtype>/<str:deg>',
         views.view_org_db, name='view_org'),
    path('token/<str:orgtype>/<str:deg>', views.get_token, name='token'),
    path('token/<str:orgtype>', views.get_token, name='token'),
    path('create/<str:orgtype>/<str:deg>',
         views.create_user, name='create_user'),
    path('search/', views.search_user, name='search_user'),
    path('report/', views.view_report, name='view_report'),
    path('view/<int:id>', views.view_user, name='view_user')
]
```

Comment: <a href="{% url 'create_user' orgtype deg %}">Создать нового пользователя</a>

Use like this if you passed 'orgtype' and 'deg' in context.

Need more clarification in your question

Comment: I tried it, no data was sent to url

Comment: Need more clarification in question are you want to submit data to url?
{{request.path}} is used to get corrent url

Comment: @ShiBilPK I need to redirect by {% url %} tag to another page with same url parameters, such as orgtype and deg